# Show the computers on my wifi

Tags: powershell

I want see an output which **shows the DNS** (Alexander-PC, Joe-PC...), their MAC and IP addresses.

I've tested with:

```
# Only shows my PC
$connectedComputers = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem
$connectedComputers.UserName

# This doesn't show the DNS of the computers (Alexander-PC, for example)
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration
```

Comment: Do you mean the computername? If so, try $env:COMPUTERNAME

Comment: The computername of the computers connected on my wifi, not only my PC.

Comment: Do you mean all the computers on your domain?

Comment: My domain? If you are saying my router, yes.

Comment: I don't think these information are available on your computer so you may need to invoke a web request to your router.

Comment: If your router's network is partitioned, you'll not be able to get anything beyond your PC's local network segment, unless you request the data from the router. And usually wireless networks are partitioned from LAN by using VLAN tags. Sometimes even if two PCs are connected to one WIFI SSID they happen to be on an "isolated" VLAN meaning that they cannot communicate with each other, so you won't be able to get any MAC addresses on any PC except its own and the router's.

Comment: Ok, but this isn't my case. With an app in my phone I've shown my computer and my mobile.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you want to enumerate your network neighborhood. If you have Windows 8 or newer there's that [`Get-NetNeighbor`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh826147%28v=wps.630%29.aspx) cmdlet that will list the IP and MAC (link-layer) addresses from the cache:

```
PS C:\> Get-NetNeighbor -AddressFamily IPv4 | select IPAddress, LinkLayerAddress | ft -AutoSize

IPAddress       LinkLayerAddress
---------       ----------------
224.0.0.252     01005e0000fc
224.0.0.22      01005e000016
192.168.56.255  ffffffffffff
192.168.56.1    000000000000
224.0.0.22      01005e000016
239.255.255.250
224.0.0.22
255.255.255.255 ffffffffffff
239.255.255.250 01005e7ffffa
224.0.0.252     01005e0000fc
224.0.0.22      01005e000016
192.168.13.255  ffffffffffff
192.168.13.12   00d02bd17940
192.168.13.15   00000c9ff1ff
```

If you have working reverse DNS you can get the DNS names for a given IP address with the [`Resolve-DnsName`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh826147%28v=wps.630%29.aspx) cmdlet.

```
PS C:\> Resolve-DnsName 192.168.13.15

Name                           Type   TTL   Section    NameHost
----                           ----   ---   -------    --------
15.13.168.192.in-addr.arpa.    PTR    900   Question   test.example.com
```

On Windows versions prior to Windows 8 you could use `arp -a` and `nslookup`.

Comment: In case of a router domain, there might not be a DNS name to resolve for say `192.168.1.4`, in this case, `Resolve-DNSName` should be called with [`-NetbiosFallback`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj590781%28v=wps.630%29.aspx) switch parameter set.

Comment: Hello! With Get-NetNeighbor I only get invalid directions (I want say that my computer or my mobile aren't in the list). I've checked their IPsv4 and DNSs manually in my router.

Comment: Your only other option is to log into your router and extract the information from there. How that can be achieved depends on the router model and is far too broad a question to be answered here.